# How do I average D rows in E column in excel using INT formula?

Tags: excel

How do I average D rows in E column in excel using INT formula? 
For making difference I used formula =INT(C3-B3) & " days, " & HOUR(C3-B3) & " hours, " & MINUTE(C3-B3) & " minutes and " & SECOND(C3-B3) & " seconds"

```
A   B   C   D   E
1   Logged date Resolved date   Resolution Time (Resolved date – Logged date)   Average Resolution Time (D2 to D6 row)
2   20-12-15 16:09  01-06-16 16:42  164 days, 0 hours, 33 minutes and 0 seconds  
3   23-12-15 11:56  01-05-16 16:50  130 days, 4 hours, 54 minutes and 0 seconds  
4   28-12-15 12:25  01-05-16 16:47  125 days, 4 hours, 22 minutes and 0 seconds  
5   30-12-15 10:06  01-02-16 17:37  33 days, 7 hours, 31 minutes and 0 seconds   
6   30-12-15 10:06  01-04-16 17:06  93 days, 7 hours, 0 minutes and 0 seconds
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this array formula:

```
=INT(AVERAGE(B2:B6-A2:A6)) & " days, " & HOUR(AVERAGE(B2:B6-A2:A6)) & " hours, " & MINUTE(AVERAGE(B2:B6-A2:A6)) & " minutes and " & SECOND(AVERAGE(B2:B6-A2:A6)) & " seconds"
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting Edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

[image]

Comment: @Ahad please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer